# Why is my socket.io emit not causing a refresh of content

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express, socket.io

I have been adapting the IBM angularjs tutorial [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-nodejs-polling-app/) into a Yeoman angular-fullstack tutorial and it has been relatively easy except I have one Issue. When I vote on a Poll the data does not refresh and show the results on my version.

I have tried Debugging through it as best I can and I cannot see any difference between my version and the IBM version that would cause this issue. I have also looked here on SO and on google but I'm actually completely lost.

my entire code base is located here on [github](https://github.com/jonniedarko/poller) and I have embeded what I think is the relevant code below, Any help would be greatly appreciated

This is the client side controller

```
    .controller('PollViewCtrl', function ($scope, $routeParams, Poll, socket){
        $scope.poll = Poll.get({pollId: $routeParams.id});
        socket.on('myvote', function(data) {
                console.dir(data);
                if(data._id === $routeParams.pollId) {
                  $scope.poll = data;
                }
              });
              socket.on('vote', function(data) {
                console.dir(data);
                if(data._id === $routeParams.pollId) {
                  $scope.poll.choices = data.choices;
                  $scope.poll.totalVotes = data.totalVotes;
                }
              });
              $scope.vote = function() {
                var pollId = $scope.poll._id,
                    choiceId = $scope.poll.userVote;
                if(choiceId) {
                  var voteObj = { poll_id: pollId, choice: choiceId };
                  socket.emit('send:vote', voteObj);
                } else {
                  alert('You must select an option to vote for');
                }
              };
      })
```

and this is the relavent server side code

```
//app.js
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app.listen(config.port));
var poll = require('./lib/controllers/polls');
io.sockets.on('connection', poll.vote);

//poll.js
exports.vote = function(socket) {
  socket.on('send:vote', function(data) {
    var ip = socket.handshake.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || socket.handshake.address.address;
    Poll.findById(data.poll_id, function(err, poll) {
      var choice = poll.choices.id(data.choice);
      choice.votes.push({ ip: ip });
      poll.save(function(err, doc) {
        var theDoc = {
          question: doc.question, _id: doc._id, choices: doc.choices,
          userVoted: false, totalVotes: 0
        };
        for(var i = 0, ln = doc.choices.length; i < ln; i++) {
          var choice = doc.choices[i];
          for(var j = 0, jLn = choice.votes.length; j < jLn; j++) {
            var vote = choice.votes[j];
            theDoc.totalVotes++;
            theDoc.ip = ip;
            if(vote.ip === ip) {
              theDoc.userVoted = true;
              theDoc.userChoice = { _id: choice._id, text: choice.text };
            }
          }
        }
        socket.emit('myvote', theDoc);
        socket.broadcast.emit('vote', theDoc);
      });
    });
  });
};
```

### Update

Here is the factory for socket

```
.factory('socket', function($rootScope) {
        var socket = io.connect();
        return {
          on: function (eventName, callback) {
            socket.on(eventName, function () {
              var args = arguments;
              $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                callback.apply(socket, args);
              });
            });
          },
          emit: function (eventName, data, callback) {
            socket.emit(eventName, data, function () {
              var args = arguments;
              $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                if (callback) {
                  callback.apply(socket, args);
                }
              });
            })
          }
        };
      });;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was simply a mix up of variable name, while IBM was using `pollId` in their route for getting a poll I was using `id` but had managed to use `pollId` in my controller, once I changed this all behaved as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make an apply when you're receiving the sockent on AngularJS because socket.io is not "in the AngularJS world".

You have a rerally great tutorial here to do what you want : 
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/frameworks/angular-websockets/?redirect_from_locale=fr

If you have any questions just ask it !

Hope it helps

Comment: but I am using `$apply` on the rootScope see the update I provided

Comment: Have you got an error in your browser console like : '$apply already in progress' or '$digest already in progress' ?

Comment: No I receive no error, in fact on the line starting `socket.on('myvote', function(data) { console.dir(data); ...` of my controller I successfully get the data in the console, just content doesn't seem to be updating

Comment: I just found the Issue, I wasn't retrieving the correct params, IBM were using $routeParams.pollId but somewhere along the line I mixed something up and this should $routeParams.id. Thank you for your assistance though